# How to solve the error and how to do better way using oops concept?

Tags: java

I am learning java program. I have a question to solve . the question is

```
enter the no . of people:
enter the product_name, price, stock_available:
total amount is price * no. of people
```

if the stock available is less than the no of people the print value 0

Example:

```
**input:**
 no . of people : 3
product_name, price, stock_available: book, 100, 3
**output:** 300


public class Product {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the no . of people:");
    int people=sc.nextInt();
    String[] string = new String [3]; 
    System.out.println("Enter the product_name, price, quantity_available:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)   
    {  
        string[i] = sc.nextLine();  
    }
    
    int quantity=Integer.parseInt(string[2]); 
    int price=Integer.parseInt(string[1]);
    if(people<=quantity) {
        System.out.println("Total amout is:"+(price*people));
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("value is "+0);
    }
    
}
}
```

**console error:**

```
Enter the no . of people:
3
Enter the product_name, price, quantity_available:
book
30
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "book"
```

How to solve this error and how to do better way using oops concept ?

Comment: What comes after `For input string`? Can you post the entire stack trace that it logs?

Comment: @rb612  Thanks for the response. I have updated.. sc.next(); now it is working . please suggest how to implement oops concept here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Loop I always prefer to read input using next() .

Using next() will only return what comes before the delimiter (defaults to whitespace). nextLine() automatically moves the scanner down after returning the current line.

As you were using `sc.nextLine()` this may one reason you were getting `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.

Try as `sc.next();` to read your input

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are using :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    string[i] = sc.nextLine();
}
```

this `sc.nextLine()` while taking input. Now the problem is `sc.nextLine()` reads a line until `'\n'` or `enter` is encountered. Now, for the first cycle in for loop it it putting a `'\n'` in the buffer. Because nextLine() stop taking input while `'\n'` encountered. So, In the next cycle the value of `string[1] = '\n'`. And when you try to parse this to an Integer then an error occurs. Because this is not an Integer.

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the no . of people:");

        int people = sc.nextInt();

        String[] string = new String [3];

        System.out.println("Enter the product_name, price, quantity_available:");

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            string[i] = sc.next();
        }

        int price = Integer.parseInt(string[1]);
        int quantity = Integer.parseInt(string[2]);

        if(people <= quantity) {
            System.out.println("Total amount is: "+ (price*people));
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("value is: "+0);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extra sc.nextLine() just before the loop...

```
sc.nextLine() ----> add this line
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)   
{          
    string[i] = sc.nextLine();  
}
```

when you press enter after getting the value of people... your string[] array takes a value in its 0 index position. So the nextLine scans only 2 values from the console and then throws an exception.
On that time your string[] values are = {"", "NAME", "PRICE"}

And you are trying to parse a string value (NAME) to int

Answer (score 0):

According to your input style, your code does not serve your purpose.

`Problem:`

Case 1: You tried to input something like:

```
product_name, price, stock_available: book, 100, 3
```

But in your code, using for loop you tried to get 3 string values.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)   
{  
    string[i] = sc.nextLine();  
}
```

So, after first input, when you press `enter` without any input, it throws `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`

Case 2: nextLine() scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.

Since this method continues to search through the input looking for a line separator, `it may buffer all of the input searching for the line to skip if no line separators are present`. And this is the reason, you may get this exception.

when the loop executes, string[0]'s value will be ""/blank string, which it gets from the buffered line separator. string[1]'s value will be your first string input(product_name).

so, when you tried to parse it as int, it threw number format exception.

`Solution:`

Case 1. If you want to take input in one line then, do not use `for loop`. Get input as a string and parse it to get your values.

```
String[] string = new String[3];
String inputString = null;System.out.println("Enter the product_name, price, quantity_available:");

inputString=sc.next();

string=inputString.split(",");

String product = string[0];
int quantity = Integer.parseInt(string[2]);
int price=Integer.parseInt(string[1]);
```

Case 2. If you do not solve the buffered line separator issue, then you should use next() method to take input.

---

This is very simple application. So, oop concept is not necessary for the current context.